# $location replace not removing entries from browser history

Tags: angularjs

Any idea why neither:

`$location.url(redirectURL,true);`

~ OR ~

`$location.path(redirectURL).replace(true);`

Are not replacing navigation history items?
Or did I not understand what replace is supposed to do?

Thanks.

Comment: What is going to do, is navigate to the new URL, not recording the current page in the browser history (i.e. no back to the current URL).

Comment: The `replace()` method does not take any arguments. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/location.js#L431-L435

Comment: Any hints would be awesome. :)

Answer (score 2):

Call `replace` first, as:

```
$location.replace();
$location.path("somewhere");
```

I think this works too:

```
$location.replace().path("somewhere");
```

Comment: I'll give that a try, although it should not matter because the digest happens afterwards. Also: (1) in AngularJS docs, replace is called second and (2) what about `url()` method?

Comment: having the same issue, it's not working for me either.